# Is dancing on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I see someone posted a [dancing question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4231/1723).  This is the first question with the [dancing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dancing) tag.

Is dancing on topic here?

There was a [Dancing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49985/dancing) at Area51, but it closed after 1 year without progressing.

Dancing is a physical activity, and it can be competitive.

Answer (score 4):

If the dance is danced competitively such as in Ball Room Dancing competitions, then it's definitely on topic.

If it's not then no.

Comment: It sounds like people have never heard about competitive dancing, of course, for example with Flamenco: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-_Wi9VAmTY

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb when considering if a general activity is on-topic for Sports SE is to consider if the activity can be considered competitive.

The on-topic page states:

> Sports Stack Exchange is for participants, hobbyists, and fans of all
>   sports and forms of competitive physical activity.

I have a hard time specifying general dance as on-topic. Again, competitive dance is on-topic, as long as it is clear that it is about competitive aspects. Competitive aspects include preparation/judging mechanisms/history for said competitive dance to explore a few of potentially many topics.

---

However, some exceptions arise when it comes to expertise. For example, [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4089) was about running in marathons, but expertise was better served at Fitness SE. It can be on-topic for both sites, but discretion shall be used to give the question the best opportunity to obtain good answers.

Comment: Here's an example presenting the dichotomy between Fitness and Sports SE for running: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/35